# openDDS not generating typesupportc header

Tags: idl, tao, opendds

Im running into an issue with getting TAO_idl not generating typesupportc header.  the dds_TAOv2_all.sln builds just fine and all the examples generate their respectful typesupport files including the typesupportc.h file that is necessary for the typesupport_var in my IDL file.

```
module X {

#pragma DCPS_DATA_TYPE "X::packet"
#pragma DCPS_DATA_KEY "X::packet from"
typedef sequence<octet> binary;
struct packet {
    string from;
    long packet_id;
    long   count;
long timer;
binary mydata;
  };
};
```

the Xtypesupportc.h was genereated before, but ever since I had to reload DDS(DDS is compiled configured etc) when I run tao_idl and openDDS_idl with the x.idl file the xtypesupportc and xtypesupports don't get created and thus I can't register the type.  any obvious thing that I am doing wrong? thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to put the pragma before the module X declaration, you now place it inside the module.

Comment: yes just did, same result, the typesupportc and s headers never get created.  I had to rebuild the DDS solution again but the example files generate just fine.